# filestream - open excel file read only fails

Tags: excel, vb.net, filestream, syncfusion

I read an excel file (.xlsm; password-protected) with a vb.net application. I use the following interfaces:

- System.IO.filestream
- Syncfusion.XlsIO (NuGet)

That works, but I want to open it in ReadOnly-Mode, so that any other people can use this file with MS Office (write, save, ...).

Code:

```
Imports Syncfusion.XlsIO

Private SyncEE As Syncfusion.XlsIO.ExcelEngine
Private SyncWB As Syncfusion.XlsIO.IWorkbook

Private SyncFS As System.IO.FileStream

Public Sub new

 SyncEE = New ExcelEngine
 SyncFS = New FileStream(PathFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
 SyncEE.Excel.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2016

 SyncWB = SyncEE.Excel.Workbooks.Open(SyncFS, ExcelParseOptions.Default, openReadOnly, password)
 SyncWB.Unprotect(password)
 SyncWB = SyncEE.Excel.Workbooks.Open(SyncFS, ExcelOpenType.Automatic)

 ' read....

 
'discard
 SyncWB.Close()
 SyncWB = Nothing

 SyncEE.Dispose()
 SyncEE = Nothing

 SyncFS.Dispose()
 SyncFS = Nothing

End Sub
```

I tried it step by step and found out that i block the file at row:

```
SyncFS = New FileStream(PathFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

and I release the file at the 'discard' rows.

Blocking means that no one can edit and save the excel-file manually in MS Excel while I read it.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion.

You are blocking the file on loading the file using FileStream, as mentioned by you and you are discarding the FileStream object only at the end of your entire program. You can discard the FileStream object immediately after loading it into a workbook object so that others can use the file with MS Office (write, save, …) while you are reading it. Hence, we have modified your code as below to achieve your requirement.

**Code snippet:**

```
Private Sub new

    SyncEE = New ExcelEngine
    SyncFS = New FileStream(PathFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    SyncEE.Excel.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2016

    SyncWB = SyncEE.Excel.Workbooks.Open(SyncFS, ExcelParseOptions.Default, openReadOnly, password)

    'Discard FileStream
    SyncFS.Dispose()
    SyncFS = Nothing

    ' read....


    'discard
    SyncWB.Close()
    SyncWB = Nothing

    SyncEE.Dispose()
    SyncEE = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Note:** I work for Syncfusion.

Regards,
Shamini

Comment: thats true, another attempt was not to use Filestream, so therefore is used the Workbooks.open Method with other parameters:

SyncWB = SyncEE.Excel.Workbooks.Open(Me.PathFile, ExcelParseOptions.StringsReadOnly, openReadOnly, password, ExcelOpenType.Automatic)
SyncWB.Unprotect(password)

During the Workbooks.open Method  runs(it takes a few seconds, because excel file is big), the file is blocked - Other user cannot save the file in MS Excel manually.